# Can Ruby on Rails Routes point a nested URL at a single action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

Is it possible in Ruby on Rails (we're using v2 still) to allow the routes file to map a nested url EG

mydomain.com/controller/object/action

to a single action eg

:controller, :action

?

We currently have a url like
mydomain.com/controller/action 
and i want to change it to
mydomain.com/controller/object/action

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's called as `member route`

Answer (score 0):

You can write singular route like as follow. You will get record id in params[:id] in controller action.

```
match 'controller/:id/action' => 'controller#action', via: :get
```

Comment: If it's Rails < v4, you may need to do `match 'controller/:id/action' => 'controller#action', via: :get`